# Get value from dictionary in JavaScript by key

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `JavaScript` script I have created following dictionary.

```
var dictionary =[];
$(function () {
  dictionary.push({
    key: @item.Key.ToShortDateString().ToString(),
    value: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value)),
  });
  alert(dictionary['2017-09-19']);
});
```

In alert it shows me `undefined`. How can I read value from this dictionary?

Comment: date 2017-09-19 is added eariler as a key.

Comment: You have an ***array***, it's not a dictionary, and it doesn't have named keys, but indexes. Your array contains objects though. It seems you wanted an object instead of the array

Comment: It also turned out that key must be saved using @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject to read value by key as a date saved in string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using an array use an object

```
$(function () {
  var dictionary = {};
  dictionary[@item.Key.ToShortDateString().ToString()] = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Value));
  alert(dictionary['2017-09-19']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable dictionary is an array which consists of objects. If you want to access you need to access by index.

**DEMO**

```js
 var dictionary = [];
 dictionary.push({
    key: '2017-09-19',
    value: 'test',
  });
var result = dictionary.filter(function(element) {
    return element.key == '2017-09-19';
});

if (result.length > 0) {
    // we have found a corresponding element
     console.log(result[0].value);
}
```

Comment: This will be slow. It is of order O(n)